# Encryption and Descyption issue in Flutter and C#

Tags: c#, encryption, flutter

I am using encryption in Flutter using the link: https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt

Code is

```
    final plainText = 'some plain text here';
    final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('16 characters key');
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key,mode: AESMode.cbc,padding: 'PKCS7'));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
    print(decrypted); 
    print(encrypted.base64);
```

C# code (for decryption)

```
public static String TestDecrypt(String encryptedText)
{
    var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(encryptedBytes, GetRijndaelManaged("16 characters key")));
}

public static RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
{
     var keyBytes = new byte[16];
     var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);

     Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));

     return new RijndaelManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = 128,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Key = keyBytes,
            IV = keyBytes
        };
}
```

I encrypt some plaintext in flutter dart code, But I didn't get proper plain text after decrypting the encrypted text using c# code.

I'm getting a message

> Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Comment: A key is not 16 bytes long just because it says it is :)

Comment: `IV = keyBytes` is suspicious and `    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);` is as well. Whatever you're doing, it is **not** secure. To find out what is happening, print all the input / output to AES out in hexadecimals - mainly key and IV - and check that they are identical on both sides. The key is the most likely culprit if your plaintext is indeed over 16 characters / bytes in size.

Comment: Don’t set both Key and KeySize. Each updates/resets the other.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:
Keys:

```
String keySTR = "16 characters"; //16 byte
String ivSTR = "16 characters"; //16 byte
```

Flutter

```
final plainText = 'Works!';

final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8(keySTR);
final iv = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8(ivSTR);
final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key,mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc,padding: 'PKCS7'));
final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
print('decrypted:'+decrypted);
print('encrypted.base64:'+encrypted.base64);
```

C#

```
using (System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged rjm = 
                        new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged 
                            { 
                                KeySize = 128, 
                                BlockSize = 128, 
                                Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keySTR),
                                IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ivSTR) 
                            }
            )
        {           
                Byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
                Byte[] output = rjm.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(output);                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below the line in flutter

final iv = IV.fromUtf8('16 characters key');

Answer (score 0):

@karpediemnow's answer is correct, just a small change in the C# call:

```
public static string decrypter(string text)
    {
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged rjm =
                    new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
                    {
                        KeySize = 128,
                        BlockSize = 128,
                        Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keySTR),
                        IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ivSTR)
                    }
        )
        {
            byte[] input = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            byte[] output = rjm.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output);
        }
    }
```